# bash, return position of the smallest entry in an array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array in bash. For example

```
array=(1 3 4e-10 6 4 2e-4 7 5 2 9)
```

I would like to know how to return position of the smallest number, in this case 3.

Comment: Bash doesn't do floats.

Comment: Isn't 0.0000000004 (or in your terms 4e-10) the smallest number?  ( [Link to scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)

Comment: He's assuming 1-based indexing, so 4e-10 is at position 3 in the array (I had the same thought at first).

Comment: since bash doesnt do floats, is it possible by using awk or something similar?

Comment: As a side note, `ksh` does floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ array=(1 3 4e-10 6 4 2e-4 7 5 2 9)
$ echo "${array[*]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | awk 'NR==1{min=$0}NR>1 && $1<min{min=$1;pos=NR}END{print min,pos}'
4e-10 3
```

or just

```
$ echo "${array[*]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | awk 'NR==1{min=$0}NR>1 && $1<min{min=$1;pos=NR}END{print pos}'
3
```

to get just the position.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
arr=(1 3 4e-10 6 4 2e-4 7 5 2 9)
```

for min value and position

```
echo "${arr[@]}" | tr -s ' ' '\n' | awk '{print($0" "NR)}' |
sort -g -k1,1 | head -1
4e-10 3
```

for position of min value

```
echo "${arr[@]}" | tr -s ' ' '\n' | awk '{print($0" "NR)}' |
sort -g -k1,1 | head -1 | cut -f2 -d' '
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments say, Bash doesn't do floats.  I'd loop through the array and use perl or awk.  Something like this should work:

```
for i in ${array[@]}; do echo $i; done | perl -e 'use strict; my @array; while(<STDIN>) { chomp $_; push (@array,$_+0); } foreach my $number (sort {$a <=> $b} @array) { print "$number\n"; } '
```

Answer (score 1):

A very "line-noisy" combination of bash and perl

```
array=(1 3 4e-10 6 4 2e-4 7 5 2 9)
perl -lanE '
    say 1 + (sort {$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]} map {[$_, $F[$_]]} 0..$#F)[0]->[0] 
' <<< "${array[@]}"
```

outputs `3`